# Preencher items de um DropdownButton com valor de um Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Tenho um campo `DropDownMenu` e gostaria de preencher os `Items` dele com os valores do meu Json. Eu tenho este código:

```
String _mySelection;
List<Map> _myJson = [{"id":0,"name":"<New>"},{"id":1,"name":"Test Practice"}];`
```

Que funciona no `DropDownMenu`:

```
items: _myJson.map((Map map) {
   return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: map["id"].toString(),
       child: new Text(
       map["name"],
      ),
    );
}).toList(),`
```

Porém o que eu queria, era no lugar de passar o Json montado no `_mySelection` seria passar o valor retornado da minha classe `ResultLogin`

```
static ResultLogin fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>  json) {

   List<ZLoginResultSchema> schemasList = [];

   for (var s in json['schemas']) {
     schemasList.add(ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(s));
   }
}
```

Minha classe `ZLoginResultSchema` onde monto a lista de `schemas`:

```
class ZLoginResultSchema  {
  final String name;
  final String fullname;

  ZLoginResultSchema({this.name, this.fullname});

  ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    name    = json['name'],
    fullname = json['fullname'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'name': name,
    'fullname': fullname,
  };
}
```

Como posso pegar o valor do `schemaList` da classe `ResultLogin`, e passar na Função `_myJson` da minha Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi completamente o que você estar querendo, principalmente porque não entendi o que de fato é esse seu `_mySelection`, se é uma função ou o quê. Mas pelo que entendi você quer retornar o valores de `schemaList` que nada mais é do que uma lista de Map's:

```
static List resultLogin fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>  json) {

   List<ZLoginResultSchema> schemasList = [];

   for (var s in json['schemas']) {
     schemasList.add(ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(s));
   }
return schemasList;
}
```

Será retornado uma lista de Map do tipo `ZLoginResultSchema`. E você poderá obtê-lo normalmente da lista

Comment: o _MySelection é apenas a variavel que guardarei o valor selecionado, consegui obter os valores da lista passando diretamente a classe da lista no map.               ` items: schemas.map((ZLoginResultSchema map) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: map.name,
                              child: new Text(map.fullname),
                            );
                          }).toList()`